# How can I connect a .css-file to a wikipage where the html-code disappears when I save the page?

Tags: html, css, href, wiki

I tried connecting a wikipage with a `.css-file` which is included on the page as an attachment. The html-code on the page was this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_ein_ausklappen.css"/>
```

It didn't work out because the html-code disappeared and only the code `<link/>` is left.

I already tried connecting the wikipage with a css-file in a Sharepoint(database) but that also didn't work out even though the `href` command was still there after I saved the wikipage.

The html-code which was left looked kind of like this:

```
<link href="https://wiki/ksldsld.css" type="text/css"/>
```

It would be great if someone knows a good solution.

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us?

Comment: Do you want the code to appear as text-on-page (as appears in your question), or do you want to add it as a stylesheet so it alters the appearance of the page?

Comment: What happens if you just add the css in behind style tags instead of linking to it?

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King I want to add it as a stylesheet so that I can change the design(appearance) of the wikipage.

Answer (score 0):

@Ralph I tried adding the .css in the html-code like this:

```
<h1 dir="ltr">HELLO WORLD</h1>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {color: blue} 
</style>
```

but the title "HELLO WORLD" is still black after I save the wikipage and the code inside the style tag disappears and only this code is left in the wikipage:

```
<h1 dir="ltr">HELLO WORLD</h1>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
```

I really don't know how I can add a stylesheet to a wikipage and alter the appearance of the page if the code disappears even if I put the code inside a `<style>` tag...